# Can jackson parser Object from json if I add or delete some field?

Tags: json, jackson

In my work, I want to use jackson in this situation:

```
{
  "student": {
      "name" : "hello",
      "id" : "STU_001"
  }
}
```

Then, I define a class student:

```
class Student {
   public String name;
   public String id;
   //get and set methods
}
```

but, in some case, the json will be:

```
{
  "student": {
      "name" : "hello",
      "id" : "STU_001",
      "age" : "23"
  }
}
```

or:

```
{
  "student": {
      "name" : "hello"
  }
}
```

All in all, I want to use Jackson to parser the students data, when the json add or delete some filed, how can I solve it with Jackson?

Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops!

I search it with Google, and I finally find the answer!

Use the following code:

````
```objectMapper.configure(org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);```
````

When you add a field it original don't have, it will ignore the field.When you delete a field, it will assign the field "null".